# Changing observable source during the same subscription

Tags: c#, .net, reactive-programming, system.reactive

How can I change a `Observable` source while keeping the subscription intact? Yea, this is easy to accomplish with a `Subject` but best practises says **not to use a subject**.

Here an example:

#### Worker.cs

```
public class Worker
{
    public IObservable<Worker> IsWorking {get;}
    public string Name {get;}

    public Worker(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        IsWorking = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .Select(_ => this);
    }
}
```

This class exposes an `Observable` which fires every second.

#### WorkerState.cs

```
public class WorkerState
{
    public Worker CurrentWorker
    {
        set => WorkerIsBusy = value.IsWorking;
    }

    public IObservable<Worker> WorkerIsBusy { get; private set; }
}
```

This class is supposed to hold a worker unit, which can be changed on the fly but the `Subscription` should be automatically attached to the current worker. (This is would be the place for a `Subject`)

And here the test:

#### Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public async Task Run()
    {
        var state = new WorkerState();
        state.CurrentWorker = new Worker("A");
        state.WorkerIsBusy.Subscribe(worker =>
            Console.WriteLine($"Worker {worker.Name}"));

        await Task.Delay(3000);
        
        Console.WriteLine("Should change now to B...");
        state.CurrentWorker = new Worker("B");
        
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

But my ouput is the following:

```
Worker A
Worker A
Should change now to B...
Worker A
Worker A
Worker A
...
```

instead of switching to worker B.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use Subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you should almost always use for re-subscribing is to get the query to resubscribe for you by using the `.Switch()` operator.

Something like this:

```
var switcher = new Subject<IObservable<int>>();

var subscription = switcher.Switch().Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

switcher.OnNext(Observable.Return(42));
switcher.OnNext(Observable.Range(0, 3));
```

That produces:

```
42
0
1
2
```

No re-subscription required.

For your code you need to change `WorkerState` to this:

```
public class WorkerState
{
    private Worker currentWorker = null;
    private Subject<Worker> currentWorkerSubject = new Subject<Worker>();
    public Worker CurrentWorker
    {
        set
        {
            currentWorker = value;
            currentWorkerSubject.OnNext(value);
        }
    }

    public IObservable<Worker> WorkerIsBusy
    {
        get =>
            currentWorkerSubject
                .StartWith(currentWorker)
                .Where(w => w != null)
                .Select(w => w.IsWorking)
                .Switch();
    }
}
```

Then your code works (with the minor caveat that the `await Task.Delay(3000);` has a small race condition with the `Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))` inside `Worker`. Change the `await` to `3500` to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you have is that you've subscribed to the previous value of WorkerIsBusy, and although you've changed the reference, you haven't changed the subscription, which still points at the previous value.

You would need to intercept (actually subscribe to) the worker.IsWorking in your WorkerState class, and unsubscribe / resubscribe when the property value changes.

Or you could use a Subject - I don't understand why you wouldn't?

Comment: No, you never need to unsubscribe and resubscribe.

Comment: Yes you do, but the subject does that for you. As I said, I don't understand why he didn't just use one.

Comment: How does the subject do that for you?

Comment: Yes, but's that's the `.Switch()` operator and not the subject that does it.

Comment: Okay, yes. I should have said "The solution which uses a subject does it for you".